# How is the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ determined by its values in a small open disc?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, analytic-continuation

This question pertains to the following quote from chapter 7 section 9 of "Summing it Up: From One Plus One to Modern Number Theory" by Avner Ash and Robert Gross:

> "What makes the Riemann hypothesis so hard to prove or disprove is the mysterious nature of analytic continuation. The function $\zeta(s)$ is completely determined for all $s\ne 0$ by its values in a small open disc about $s=2$ (for example), but how exactly this determination works is opaque."

For a small circular open disc centered around $s=2$ with radius r, I assume $r\le 1$ to avoid the pole at $s=1$, and perhaps the minimum disc radius is $r>\epsilon>0$.

**Question 1**: Is it true $\zeta(s)$ is completely determined for all $s\ne0$ by its values in a small open disc, and why the exclusion at $s=0$?

**Question 2**: Assuming the answer to question 1 is yes, can anyone provide insight as to how the value of $\zeta(s)$ at points outside of the disc are determined by the values of $\zeta(s)$ at points inside the disc?

I'm aware of the Cauchy formula where an integral along a contour enclosing a point $s_0$ is used to determine the value of $\zeta\left(s_0\right)$, but this question is for a very different case.

Comment: This is a general property of holomorphic functions - it is a fundamental  theorem of complex analysis.

Comment: I don't think anything "fractal" is going on here.

Comment: Keyword: Cauchy's integral formula

Comment: My understanding is Cauchy's integral formula expresses the fact that a holomorphic function $f(s)$ defined on a disk $A$ is completely determined by its values on the boundary of disk $A$. Assuming the domain of $f(s)$ is $B$ where $A\subset B$, how is Cauchy's integral formula relevant to finding the value of $f(s_0)$ for $s_0\in B$ where $s_0\notin A$ from the values of $f(s)$ contained within $A$?

Comment: $F(s) = (s-1) \zeta(s)$ is entire that is for every $s,s_0$ : $$F(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{F^{(k)}(s_0)}{k!} (s-s_0)^k$$

Comment: @reuns While the formula for an entire function such as $F(s)=(s-1)\,\zeta(s)$ is a beautiful result, I don't think this is what the authors had in mind. I added an exact quote to the question above which hopefully helps to clarify their intent.

Comment: @StevenClark I think that what reuns writes is more or less exactly what Ash and Gross had in mind: they are not alluding to a mysterious special feature of the Riemann zeta-function when they write about its analytic (well, meromorphic) continuation but just the general feature in complex analysis that a meromorphic function on $\mathbf C$ is completely determined by its values as a function on an arbitrarily small open disc.

Comment: @KCd I understand what Ash and Gross wrote is not unique to the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, but if reuns comment is what they had in mind, why did they exclude $s=0$ when what reuns wrote is for every $s\,,s_0$?

Comment: That must be a typo; should say for all $s\ne1$ (since $\zeta(s)$ isn't defined at $1$ despite analytic continuation). If you google image search analytic continuation it makes clear how continuation is the result of a process of continually picking points, finding discs of convergence of power series there, and repeating. It makes more sense to start with Re(s)>1 as a "disc" (when you deal with Mobius transformations, which are the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere, half-planes are basically discs), then extend with the Dirichlet eta function, then use reflection functional equation.

Comment: @StevenClark it was just a typo.  They meant to exclude $s = 1$, not $s = 0$, because of the pole at $s = 1$.  I have written to Ash and Gross and they confirmed it was a misprint and also that what I wrote in my previous comment is accurate.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the feedback.